# Filter table and copy to new file in Pandas (VBA-like) dynamically

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a file (CSV) containing data that looks something like this in a table format:

| ID | employee | date | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2022-01-01 | 123 | 456 |
| 2 | b | 2022-01-01 | 123 | 456 |
| 3 | a | 2022-01-01 | 123 | 456 |
| 4 | c | 2022-01-01 | 123 | 456 |
| 5 | d | 2022-01-01 | 123 | 456 |
| 6 | b | 2022-01-01 | 123 | 456 |
| 7 | e | 2022-01-01 | 123 | 456 |
| 8 | e | 2022-01-01 | 123 | 456 |

In Excel I created a macro with VBA that creates new workbooks for the table filtered by the employee column. The macro works dynamically by creating a dictionary of the unique values in column [employee] and a For Each loop that filters the original table by the key of the dictionary.
In this example it would create 5 new workbooks (for employee "a", "b", "c", "d" and "e") displaying only their corresponding data.
E.g. for employee a:

| ID | employee | date | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2022-01-01 | 123 | 456 |
| 3 | a | 2022-01-01 | 123 | 456 |

VBA code:

```
Sub Filter_Copy()

Dim rng As Range
Dim wb_new As Workbook
Dim dic As Object
Dim cell AsSub Range
Dim key As Variant

Set rng = Table1.ListObjects("table").Range
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each cell In Range("table[column]")
    dic(cell.Value) = 0
Next cell

For Each key In dic.keys
    rng.AutoFilter 5, key
    Set wb_new = Workbooks.Add
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wb_new.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    wb_new.Close True, ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & key & ".xlsx"
    
Next key

End Sub
```

Now I want to do the exact same in Python but I am lost with using a `for loop` to loop through a dictionary of the unique values in [employee]. I have no troubles doing it manually for every employee by creating a dedicated dataframe for each unique value, filtering it like `df.employee == "a"` and saving it `to_excel()` but doing it dynamically is something different.

So far I have the obvious:

```
import pandas as pd

file = "filename.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(file)

dict = dict(df["employee"].unique())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pandas.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups) and iterate through them:

```
groupobj = df.groupby('employee')
for name,group in groupobj:
    group.to_excel(f'./{name}.xlsx')
```